# ActionScript 3 stage width

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im doing my first flash AS game, so need a little help.
I have only 1 thing on the stage, its ball (layer instance) which has anchor point in the middle. I'm trying to make this ball bounce off walls (i mean screen).

This instance name is called 'kugla1'

Heres my code (its second frame):

```
if(kugla1.x<=kugla1.width/2 || kugla1.x>=stage.stageWidth-kugla1.width/2)
speedX=-speedX;
if(kugla1.y<=kugla1.height/2 || kugla1.height>=stage.stageHeight-kugla1.height/2)
speedY=-speedY;

kugla1.x+=speedX;
kugla1.y+=speedY;
```

First frame is:

```
var speedX:int=5;
var speedY:int=5;

kugla1.x=100;
kugla1.y=100;
```

And third frame is only:

```
gotoAndPlay(2);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You neglect to state what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, is likely this line:

```
if(kugla1.y<=kugla1.height/2 || kugla1.height>=stage.stageHeight-kugla1.height/2)
```

In the second part (after the `||`) you are comparing the height of `kugla1` instead of the `y` position.

Another issue you could run into, is your ball could potentially meet the same condition for longer than one frame, so it would be best to separate your speed from the current direction of movement.

See code comments:

On your first frame, you'll need two additional variables:

```
var speedX:int=5;
var speedY:int=5;
var curSpeedX:Number = speedX;
var curSpeedY:Number = speedY;
```

on your second frame:

```
if(kugla1.x <= kugla1.width/2){
    curSpeedX = speedX; //we need the positive value to make it go right
}
if(kugla1.x >= stage.stageWidth - kugla1.width/2){
    curSpeedX = -speedX; //we need the negative value to make it go left
}

if(kugla1.y <= kugla1.height/2){
    curSpeedY = speedY; //we need the positive value to make it go down
}

if(kugla1.y >= stage.stageHeight - kugla1.height/2){
    curSpeedY = -speedY; //we need the negative value to make it go up
}

kugla1.x+= curSpeedX;
kugla1.y+= curSpeedY;
```